# SQL query for non like records

Tags: sql

I am a newbie at SQL and trying to wrap my head around something and could use some help.

I have 2 tables (pardon the rough description):

**Table 1:**
|date_val | sec_id |

**Table 2:**
|item_id | sec_id | legal_name | date_val | value |

This is probably going to be really simple to some - but I just can't wrap my head around it.  I need a list (put into a new table) of all rows from Table 1 that don't have a corresponding sec_id and date_val combination on table 2.  In this case, Table 1 has all the sec_id and date_val combinations that should exist.  I just need to find those rows on Table 1 that don't have the same sec_id and date_val on Table 2. I hope this makes sense!

I was thinking WHERE NOT EXIST but sub queries are still a little new to me!

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know if a correlation exists or does not... `exists` is definitely one to consider.

Comment: You're on the right track with `not exists`. Take a shot at it and post your code.

Comment: Thanks all - I will see what I can nail down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE NOT EXISTS` is exactly what you want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.sec_id = t1.sec_id and
                        t2.date_val = t1.date_val
                 );
```

Note:  This assumes that the two columns are not `NULL`.  If you need to handle `NULL` values, then the logic can be tweaked for that.

Comment: Thanks - I will see what I can nail down!

Comment: Hey Gordon - thanks for the help.  Does it matter what I select on the subquery?  You have select 1 - does that mean just pick any single row to return?  Thx!

Comment: @Code.is.power . . . `not exists` just checks for *rows* being returned.  The value in the column(s) is immaterial.  I use `1` because it is clear and easy to type.